# Login security: can I trust php's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?

Tags: security, cookies, https, lamp

I want to include secure login in a website and, *given the threat model*, I am wondering if I can safely drop back to a faster plain connection like this:

1. Over a secure connection, negotiate a random token `T`. This is stored in a cookie.
2. The server stores `f(T)=hash(private_salt,T,username,password,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`
3. `T` is shared later on over unencrypted connections. The server recomputes `f(T)` to authenticate the connection.

The idea is that T represents no particular information, and even if it is stolen, a connection from a different originating IP address will cause the a different `f(T)` to be calculated.

The obvious weakness is session theft behind NAT. Let's say we can dismiss this in practice. The question basically boils down to: how easy is it to spoof a connection, preserving `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

This website requires only moderate security. There will not be sensitive traffic. **The threat model is basically to cope with vandalism.** I only need to deter bored people, not the Russian mafia. Given this assumption, is the above protocol sufficiently secure?

Also, let's assume this happens with a regular web browser and LAMP -- for the secure password transmission, is https the only game in town? It seems like Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange or similar would be sufficient (impersonation of the server is not in the threat model) and does not require all that signing malarkay. Is there a standard apache/php module for this which most browsers support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad idea.

I used to be on a big network that had multiple IP addresses. Every request I made was assigned to one of the IP addresses by a load balancer. Effectively this meant that my IP address was rarely the same in two consecutive requests. I would be logged out of your system every time I loaded a page.

You could try using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, as this will require the cookie thief to either have the exact same browser or (assuming the threat model allows for sufficiently skilled vandals) to forge the exact same UA string. That said, if you don't tell anyone you check the UA string, it could be puzzling to less-skilled hackers to work out what your server is rejecting about the "perfect good" session cookie.

Comment: Was this "big network" some sort of special corporate internal setup? Or is it common practice for users at home?

Comment: I was in University at the time. However the point still stands that anyone with a dynamic IP (ie. most people) will have problems staying logged in.

Comment: What if your client is mobile? Say a laptop or a phone. Then you will run into the same issue.

Comment: In most cases, when you are able to obtain a victim’s session ID, you are also able to obtain the victim’s user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

seems this wont work if: Someone steals both the IP and the cookie of the logged in user, or someone know the users acc/password.
... i fail to see how this will cope with any type of vandalism though (except maybe cookie-bruteforce/guessing attacks)  :/

also everytime the connected's IP changes, he will need to re-login..

Comment: The question could be put, succinctly, as "how hard is it to steal an IP"? Is it something a teenager could do on another continent, or would it require hacking an ISP first? This is a weakest-link problem, if they have to hack a hard middle-layer, it won't be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Interactions with websites occur using HTTP, which runs over TCP. TCP connections are persistant and the three-way handshake that occurs at the beginning of each connection setup ensures that I cannot go and lie about my IP address (as the second step in the handshake is sent from the server to the IP address specified by the client, so unless you can compromise routing tables or do some other really fancy (and very difficult) things, the connection cannot get set up).

So, especially based on the threat model you're using, do not work about IP address spoofing; for TCP connections, it's very hard to pull this off in practice. Since clients can change IP addresses (dynamic IPs issued by ISPs, load balancing proxy servers, NAT/PAT, etc), you're much more likely to incorrectly reject good users than correctly reject bad ones using this approach. Generate a good session ID, store it in the cookie, and check it upon each request.